# Syntax error, insert ":" to complete SwitchLabel

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpaswrd);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpssd);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlgin);

        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String name=username.getText().toString();
        String pwd=password.getText().toString();

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonlgin;
            break;

            if (name.equals("nana") && pwd.equals("12345")) {
                Intent i=new Intent(this, Qrcodescreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Success!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        }
        displayNextAlert();
    }

    private void displayNextAlert() {
        // Get what the user entered
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpaswrd);
        //Puts out an error message (!)
        if ( username.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            username.setError( "Username required");
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpssd);
        if ( password.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            password.setError( "Password required");
    }   
}
```

I am getting errors on the 'case R.id.buttonlgn;'. Please help. Thanks

Comment: This question has a very very low quality. Provide more code, the exception and the stacktrace

Comment: it is `case X:` and not `case X;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stackoverflow is not intended to be used as a syntax checker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must not be be semi colon after `case R.id.buttonlgin`,it must be colon.
i.e replace `case R.id.buttonlgin;` with `case R.id.buttonlgin:`and remove the first occurence of break; in your code to make your code work

Comment: if (name.equals("nana") && pwd.equals("12345")) {
            Intent i=new Intent(this, Qrcodescreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Success!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); break; } displayNextAlert(); }     It is still giving me errors. It says **Unreachable code**

Comment: which is just after the case R.id.buttonlgin:

Answer (score 2):

replace 
    case R.id.buttonlgin; with

```
case R.id.buttonlgin:
```

notice the ':'

Comment: if (name.equals("nana") && pwd.equals("12345")) {
            Intent i=new Intent(this, Qrcodescreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Success!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); break; } displayNextAlert(); }      **Unreachable code**

Comment: Then update your question to the nwe issues or create a new one

Answer (score 1):

```
 switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonlgin:
    break;
}
```

Comment: While this may be an answer to the question (I'm not familiar so I can't say for certain), your answers need to include more than just 3 lines of code.  Please explain what was wrong with the OP's issue and explain why your solution addresses that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put ":" instead of ";" after R.id.buttonlgin.

```
switch(v.getId()) {
  case R.id.buttonlgin:
  break;
}
```